# How to cite an article found on a webpage

Tags: citations, citation-style, latex

I would like to cite the following pdf found in a website online in a personal article I'm working on:

- http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/texlive-doc/latex/base/encguide.pdf

As you can see this looks like an article complete with authors and a publication date. However it is also an online resource, and there is no journal to which it is associated.

Taking into account the limitations and conventions of `biblatex`, how should I cite this document? Should I cite as a webpage or scholarly article? If the latter is preferred, what should my journal name be?

Comment: I would suggest you use the "TechReport" document type and as instutution latex-project.org. This is the original source of the document. https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf

Comment: _Taking into account the limitations and conventions of biblatex_ - I don't personally use biblatex, but TeX in general is very flexible and shouldn't limit your options on how you cite a document.  If you have a question about how to use biblatex, ask on TeX SE.